# whille checking http status code getting error saying - The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

i want to insert url/link if its a valid url. for that im checking status code . but for some links im gettig this error even though its a valid link

```
    HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(LinkCheck);
    myHttpWebRequest.Timeout = 150000;
    myHttpWebRequest.Method = "HEAD";
    myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Foo";
    myHttpWebRequest.Accept = "*/*";
    myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();//getting error here
    MyStatusCode = ((int)myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode);
    myHttpWebResponse.Close();
```

input- http://www.jabong.com/men/
output should come = 200
but its throwing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [server](http://www.jabong.com/men/) you are making a request to doesn't seem to support the `HEAD` HTTP verb. Change your request to type to `GET` and it'll work just fine:

```
myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
```